# iOS - How to not show a navigation bar on a screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I'm looking for a way to have a navigation bar not show up on a screen at all.

I know there is a `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` to use on the navigationbar, but this still shows the bar on the screen for a split second before removing and readjusting the screen dimensions.

I've tried moving the `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` to the `viewDidLoad:`, `viewWillAppear:` etc. and set it hidden on the previous activities `viewWillDisappear:` but it will shows up on the next screen.

How do I make it such that the view loads with out a navigationbar on it before it is shown?

Thanks,
Dman

Comment: check if you have multiple navigation bars.

Comment: @Parser how do I do that, there is only one navigation controller showing at the start of the app on the storyboard

Comment: can you share screenshot of the storyboard here, hopefully you didn't have make the navigation programatically.

Comment: @Parser Looking at the controller code prior to and when the navigation bar shows, there is no mention to navigationController except through calling self. Also in no place in the code do I instantiate a UINavigationViewController so I don't see that being a possibility

Comment: you have tabbar application or single view application?

Comment: @Parser Single view with navigation controller

Comment: try to NSLog the self.navigationcontroller instance, sometime after adding to view it releases.

Comment: I figured it out ... I created a master view to handle some common button presses across the screens and was hidding it in here but to my dismay I was reshowing it in some of the controllers that used this master controller and forgot to remove it from them ... embarrassing ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm hiding the navigation bar for the `UINavigationController` in the AppDelegate `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method and works fine for me. At some point, while navigating through the screens, I'm showing it then hide it again. Works like a charm.

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: controller];
navCtrl.navigationBarHidden = YES;

self.window.rootViewController = navCtrl;
[controller release];
[navCtrl release];
```

Hope this helps.

P.S. Actually I never show the navigationBar of the navigation controller again. On the controllers that need the bar I'm adding a new one.

Comment: +1 Good answer, buy why not just use the existing nav bar rather than create a new one?

Comment: This is a good way of doing it so I'll give you the answer ... rookie mistake on my part tho ... I was previously showing the navbar in the controller and forgot to remove that as I created a master view that was handling the hiding (and other events) ... *sigh*

Comment: I was using the navigationBarHidden property to hide it and was hidden/shown during the navigation animation, which I didn't want. But you have a good point. Hiding or showing the navigationBar animated using `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` in the `viewWillAppear:` method of both controllers works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and do

```
setNavigationBarHidden:animated:
```

in your view which is calling the view where you don't want it to be displayed just before you call your new view. If they have the same navigationcontroller, it should already be hidden if it appears

if not, you try to set it on the navigation oder viewcontroller before your present it...

Comment: I did this already by adding it to the viewWillDisappear of the calling controller. They should all be part of the same navigation controller which also confuses me as to why it doesn't stay hidden when I go from a view with the bar hidden and then it all of a sudden shows on the next one. The view that is calling it has it set to hidden, but once the new controller loads it is shown again